# OpenVPN with IPVanish on Linux Mint: Connects but no internet access

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to an IPVanish server on Linux Mint. IPVanish does not provide software for Linux so it has to be done manually.

I downloaded an ovpn file from IPVanish [here](http://www.ipvanish.com/software/configs/). I then went to Mint's Network Settings, hit the + button to add a network, and selected VPN. It prompted me to browse to my VPN config file and when I tried to import it I got this error

[image]

The next thing I tried was following [this tutorial](https://support.ipvanish.com/customer/portal/articles/1969179-openvpn-linux-command-line-). Using OpenVPN, I was able to connect to the service using this command as root

```
openvpn --config newyork.ovpn
```

in the directory I downloaded the .ovpn and cert files to. It prompted me for my login information and then printed this

```
Mon Nov 23 13:10:42 2015 DEPRECATED OPTION: --tls-remote, please update your configuration
Mon Nov 23 13:10:42 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.2 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Dec  1 2014
Enter Auth Username:nickgilbert1994
Enter Auth Password:
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 Deprecated TLS cipher name 'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA', please use IANA name 'TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA'
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 Deprecated TLS cipher name 'DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA', please use IANA name 'TLS-DHE-DSS-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA'
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 Deprecated TLS cipher name 'AES256-SHA', please use IANA name 'TLS-RSA-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA'
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->131072] S=[212992->131072]
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]216.151.180.2:443
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]216.151.180.2:443, sid=aad3ff40 72d53cab
Mon Nov 23 13:11:24 2015 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, /C=US/ST=FL/L=Winter_Park/O=IPVanish/OU=IPVanish_VPN/CN=IPVanish_CA/emailAddress=support@ipvanish.com
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 VERIFY X509NAME OK: /C=US/ST=FL/L=Winter_Park/O=IPVanish/OU=IPVanish_VPN/CN=nyc-a01.ipvanish.com/emailAddress=support@ipvanish.com
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, /C=US/ST=FL/L=Winter_Park/O=IPVanish/OU=IPVanish_VPN/CN=nyc-a01.ipvanish.com/emailAddress=support@ipvanish.com
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-256-CBC' initialized with 256 bit key
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 2048 bit RSA
Mon Nov 23 13:11:25 2015 [nyc-a01.ipvanish.com] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]216.151.180.2:443
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 SENT CONTROL [nyc-a01.ipvanish.com]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 198.18.0.1,dhcp-option DNS 198.18.0.2,rcvbuf 262144,explicit-exit-notify 5,route-gateway 172.20.32.1,topology subnet,ping 20,ping-restart 40,ifconfig 172.20.32.71 255.255.252.0'
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: explicit notify parm(s) modified
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --sndbuf/--rcvbuf options modified
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->425984] S=[131072->131072]
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options modified
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-option options modified
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.0.47.254/255.255.240.0 IFACE=wlan0 HWADDR=48:5a:b6:aa:19:17
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 TUN/TAP device tun0 opened
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 /sbin/ip link set dev tun0 up mtu 1500
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun0 172.20.32.71/22 broadcast 172.20.35.255
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 /sbin/ip route add 216.151.180.2/32 via 10.0.47.254
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.32.1
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 172.20.32.1
Mon Nov 23 13:11:27 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

I assume that means it connected to the IPVanish server successfully but then when I tried to go online or ping www.google.com I realized I had no internet.

Here is the output of ifconfig when I'm connected to the IPVanish server

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:1a:06:cd:26:ef  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:25337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:25337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:14440746 (14.4 MB)  TX bytes:14440746 (14.4 MB)

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:172.20.32.71  P-t-P:172.20.32.71  Mask:255.255.252.0
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:144 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:9401 (9.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5a:b6:aa:19:17  
          inet addr:10.0.42.167  Bcast:10.0.47.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a5a:b6ff:feaa:1917/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:459377 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:71371126 (71.3 MB)  TX bytes:3267392 (3.2 MB)
```

I'm fairly new to Linux and would really appreciate any help I can get on this. Thanks so much!

**UPDATE**

Traceroute to Google with VPN on

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  172.20.32.1 (172.20.32.1)  23.133 ms  25.232 ms  25.521 ms
 2  64.145.79.1 (64.145.79.1)  26.103 ms  26.134 ms  26.165 ms
 3  206.130.10.41 (206.130.10.41)  26.187 ms  26.210 ms  26.232 ms
 4  209.85.244.157 (209.85.244.157)  26.357 ms 209.85.244.145 (209.85.244.145)  26.481 ms 209.85.244.153 (209.85.244.153)  26.444 ms
 5  8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8)  26.225 ms  26.255 ms  26.281 ms
```

Result of route command with VPN on

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         172.20.32.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
default         10.0.47.254     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.0.32.0       *               255.255.240.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
128.0.0.0       172.20.32.1     128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
172.20.32.0     *               255.255.252.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
216.151.180.2   10.0.47.254     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd do is a traceroute to a common internet server. 8.8.8.8 for google DNS is usually something you can always hit. I'd then suggest posting your routing table. `ip r s` or simply `route` It says it's configuring the routes but it would be good to see if those changes are being applied properly; and of course Traceroute will actually give you an indication of where the packets are also going.

Another thing of note is that it looks suspicious that your tunnel is sending packets but receiving.

Comment: Updated question